# Problem loading images from DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, image, loading

I have problem in loading images using jquery.
My program is such that it inserts as well as deletes from the same form.
When I delete an image and inserts the image and after loading the jquery function the deleted image is shown.

I have found inconstency in dom and actual location.
The browser loads the images from dom not from actual location.

Is there any function that will force to read from dom./
delete the images in dom?

Comment: shhh! pretend you're in a library.

Answer (score 0):

A browser always loads images from a location like a folder. Images are not stored in the DOM - it's not a Database.

Image replacement: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/fir.html